# How can I add a GUI to my homework?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am currently taking Intro C++ in my college. This was a very simple homework which I had to program using 3 different methods to output "1 2 3 4". Being ahead of my current skills, how can I add visual interfaces to this program that I just wrote? I mean, I want to change colors, add buttons or picture or whatever. Is that possible?

```
//Jaehyuk Oh
//Professor Kan, Shaobai
// 2/9/2014
// HWK. 2.17
// (Printing) Write a program that prints the numbers 1 to 4 on the same line with each pair    of  adjacent numbers separated bt one space. Do this several ways:
// a) using one statement with one stream insertion operation.
// b) using one statement with four stream insertion operators.
// c) using four statements. 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"1 2 3 4\n"; // ------> a)

    std::cout<<"1 "<<"2 "<<"3 "<<"4\n"; // ------> b)

    std::cout<<"1 "; // ----------> c) 
    std::cout<<"2 ";
    std::cout<<"3 ";
    std::cout<<"4"<<std::endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. We usually expect users to show us what they've done to solve their problems themselves. Have a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask good questions on SO.

Comment: What you are asking is quite broad / many options: windows api, MFC, forms, QT, etc.

Comment: I don't know much but I am saying the most simplest one possible.

Comment: It's called GUI, graphical user interface, not visual interface which is confusing. You need extra library such as Qt or WPF

Answer (score 2):

C++, as a language, has no idea of what is a color or a button.

The standard input is just a stream of characters and the standard output is a stream of characters. Nothing fancy.

There are environments in which you can control a few the visual aspects (like the color of text) using just special control characters, "escape sequences", but they work only if you run the program in a [terminal that supports these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (e.g. a Linux terminal).

Running the program in an environment where these escape sequences are not interpreted would just confuse the output (e.g. in a Windows console).

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying that you should only turn into your instructor what is expected of you, and nothing more. For example, if you use a GUI, you might end up implementing your above code in such a way that you don't use stream insertions.  Since that is the whole point of the assignment, your professor might give you a 0 for not using stream insertions, regardless of whether you can do something more complex or not.

However, as a project in your free-time, you can look into [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235634%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  WinForms is a library in .Net that has many GUI elements built into it - such as buttons and various text views, and it is built in C++.  As one commenter said, this is a broad question, but WinForms is a fairly easy-to-use API for GUIs in C++, so it's probably the most natural option to use, especially if you already have a Visual Studio compiler.

Since you have vs2010 express tagged, it sounds like you're set to give it a shot.

Writing GUIs can take a while to get used to, so don't be discouraged if you don't 'get it' immediately.  There are good reasons why GUI programming isn't a typical intro to programming topic.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much. your comment helped me a lot. It makes me think things differently. Maybe I am too rushing into learning more higher level programming. You are right, I should stick to my professor for now. :)